# How to add expiry date to static content ? Plus How to enable gzip compression?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, seo, page-load-time

I have combined two questions into one. Apology for it. But since theyshare relavant topic,hence did so.

I have ASP.Net MVC Site. Now I have read number of times about adding expiry date for static content and enabling gZip compression for static  content

But I am not sure how to do it. If you say adding a .httaccess file on the server. That I already did.But its not reflecting the impovement.

Here is .httacces file snippet.

```
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
 # Enable expirations
 ExpiresActive On 
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days"
 # My favicon
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
 # Images
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
 #Custom Fonts  Add correct content-type for fonts
 AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
 AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
 AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
 AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
 # Add a far future Expires header for fonts
 ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Is there anything wrong configuration with this file?

> Second,How to enable gZip compression for the site as well?

Comment: I think this belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ as two separate questions. But first google your questions since I think the answers are readily available

Comment: @mplungjan... actually I googled and after that I came to know about .httaccess file and moved it but still its not picking it..hence pasted my .httaccess file here..since its not reflecting what should I do to get it picked by browsers..

Comment: Htaccess is for apache. You need web config https://www.google.nl/search?q=gzip+asp+mvc